# Gauge updates using AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to update a gauge dynamically. From the following website I found the code to create a gauge http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/59c2c7483fb61070486835d15c807941. I used AJAX for updating the gauge but the needle is not moving.I use tornado web-framework to serve the gauge on screen. In the AJAX code I have hard coded to set the needle to zero.But the needle stays on 50. How can I make it update the value dynamically. I am new to AJAX so sorry if my code structure is bad.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    .label{
    font-size:22.5px;
    fill:#ffffff;
    text-anchor:middle;
    alignment-baseline:middle;
}
    .face{
    stroke:#c8c8c8;
    stroke-width:2;
}
    .minorTicks{
    stroke-width:2;
    stroke:white;
}
    .majorTicks{
    stroke:white;
    stroke-width:3;
}

</style>
<body>
<svg width="900" height="700"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://vizjs.org/viz.v1.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="static/assets/js/gauge.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function updategauge() {
    var myurl = "http://localhost:5500/gauge";
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: myurl,
      //data: {"macID": $("#macid input").val()},
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType: "json",

      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data.ip);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        gg.setNeedle(0); //sets the needle to zero
      }
    });
  }
  var svg = d3.select("svg");
  var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(450,350)");
  var domain = [0, 100];

  var gg = viz
    .gg()
    .domain(domain)
    .outerRadius(300)
    .innerRadius(30)
    .value(0.5 * (domain[1] + domain[0]))
    .duration(1000);

  gg.defs(svg);
  g.call(gg);

  d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "700px");

  setInterval(updategauge(), 2000);
});
```

Comment: the first thing i see wrong in the code is `setInterval(updategauge(), 2000)`, here you call the method instead of providing a function pointer to the setInterval-Method (should be `setInterval(updategauge, 2000)`). But besides that: are there any error messages? Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: No , there are no error messages.I created a jsfiddle but the gauge is not being displayed. <https://jsfiddle.net/bc7965j1/1/ >

Comment: @Xyres   I changed setInterval(updategauge, 2000)  as suggested above.  I removed the following lines from HTML code and the needle started moving but it does not update unless I reload the page.                                          crossDomain: true,
      dataType: "json",
 code console.log(data.ip);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));